# What is the default latitude & longitude on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-data, core-location

I want these double values to seed/pre-populate an sqlite file. Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.iphonedevforums.com/forum/sdk-coding-help/3096-cllocationcoordinate2d-not-giving-position-i-expect-mkmapview.html), I think it's that of Apple's Corporate Headquarters: (37.332, -122.031). Can anyone back me up on this?

Comment: Yes. One Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA.

Comment: That's true if you have your wifi turned off, otherwise it tries to retrieve your position from airport wifi connection.

Answer (score 1):

On the simulator, you are correct. But in the real world, the initial position will be the first waypoint Location Services will give you that suffice the conditions you specified. If it cannot find such a location, it will not give you a location at all.
Depending on your project, I would seed with a center location in the country where you will distribute your app first, or your office...